# Non linear optimization with objective function as a string

Tags: optimization

I am looking for a package to help me solve some non linear optimisation problems with
constraints.

The objective function f to optimize is given as a string. For example, f is given as the following string : "(x1)^2+(x2)^2".

I'd like to know : how to convert this string in a objective function ?
and what is most suitable R package designed to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATLAB to do preliminary manipulations and then run CVX on it. CVX is a library (available free for MATLAB/Python etc.) and the objective functions are pretty much specified the way you mention it. If you insist on R see

http://faculty.bscb.cornell.edu/~bien/cvxfromr.html